# Help needed in iPhone TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, header, tableview

Insted of the default header in the UITableView i implemented a custom table header using

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I used this method because i need to view my lengthy string within that header, so that i can reduce the size of the header font size.

But when i implement it in this way, the header doesn't look like separated. A separating line is missing just beneath the header. can any one help me to implement this line beneath the header...?

Thanks in advance,
Shibin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [at this article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html) about how to customize UITableView, maybe you'll find what you are looking for - there is an example how to set font/size of table header view.